# Reading two sensors at different frequencies... multiple Timer3?

Tags: timers

Originally, I had a single sensor which I was reading at 100MHz. I used Timer3 and function attached to it to do both reading and writing of the sensor data (print to com port).

Now I have added another sensor which can only be read at half the frequency. I still want to be able to write data in the same format as before for both sensor data at 100Hz, with slower sensor data just being repeated twice.

How do I handle this? Do I use multiple Timer3 attachments at different frequencies? I am planning to have three interrupts.. 1st for reading sensor A, 2nd for reading sensor B, and 3rd for writing data.

Comment: which Arduino you are using?

Comment: I am actually using Teensy 3.1

Answer (score 1):

The rule is:

- One Timer, One Interrupt.

When the timer overflows it triggers its interrupt. It only has one. That interrupt then runs your ISR.

If you are using a library to provide abstraction from the timer registers then it is down to that library how it calls your ISR. It is possible for one to provide a mechanism whereby you can "attach" multiple routines to the same interrupt, but that is quite a lot of work and overhead for a simple timer library to provide, so it is highly unlikely anyone would ever bother.

So how do you do multiple sensor measurements from one timer? Simple: just do multiple sensor measurements. You don't have to restrict yourself to just reading one sensor within your interrupt - you can read as many as you like. There is just a couple of caveats though:

1. The whole ISR must take less that 10ms to run or it will overrun the timer overflow period.
2. You cannot do serial from inside an interrupt<sup>*</sup>

So in your interrupt you read the sensors and add their values to a buffer. Then in your main loop you read that buffer to send the data out through serial. You may want to set a flag in your interrupt routine to alert the main loop that there is data available, or implement a circular buffer which has an equivalent of a `.available()` function to see if there is any data to read from it.

---

<sup>*You can place data in the serial TX buffer but it will not be transmitted out of the TX buffer until after the interrupt routine has finished. If you put too much data in that TX buffer it will block indefinitely waiting for it to empty.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, this is best solved by having an ISR which always reads the high rate sensor, but implements a toggle so that it only ready the low rate sensor every other execution.  On the times when you don't read it you could repeat a stored version of the last reading, though it would be more bandwidth efficient not to transmit that at all.

However, practically speaking this may not be the best choice.  The process of reading sensors often has a latency - typically to achieve the highest possible rate you would need to start the reading, and claim the result sometime later.  If your two sensors have distinct interfaces, or even if the they share an I2C or SPI bus, you may be able to start readings for both and then claim them with subsequent transactions after allowing them an overlapped measurement time.

It is also not clear that you are best to use an interrupt service routine at all.  If your MCU has nothing else to do, the most *deterministic* and ultimately *fastest* behavior on an ATmega might be to accomplish reading and direct (unbuffered) serial transmission within the main program loop, busy waiting at each phase.  This avoids not only the overhead of context switches when entering an ISR, but also a lot of the variability.  That would be doubly true if you can be transmitting the old reading while waiting for the already-triggered sensors to measure the next one.

However, you mentioned you are using a Teensy 3.x, which probably communicates natively via USB, rather than a serial UART.  That complicates things a bit - so called "serial" output flows in response to interrupts from the USB engine responding to the host, which is not really deterministic for you.  Fortunately, the Teensy is enough faster that you are less likely to have issues with running out of time, particularly when sampling at 100 Hz.